# How format values in IEnumerable view model in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vouchertype == "P" ? "Paid" : "Receipt")

&

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dated.ToString("dd-MMM-yy"))
```

Trying to format the value but error occurs:

> Template can use only with field access, property access, single dimension array index or single parameter custom indexer experssions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume posted lines are part of `forech` or other loop, and we speak about single item at that point.

In your Lambda expression you should use `modelItem` variable instead on `item`

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.vouchertype == "P" ? "Paid" : "Receipt")

&

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.dated.ToString("dd-MMM-yy"))
```

In `Lambda expression` rule is following:

```
x => x become your variable
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: thanks for knowlegding me about lambda experession . this worked : @(item.dated.ToString("dd-MMM-yy"))